# Where is System.Diagnostics.Process in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-phone-8

I have run into a problem where a part of my code in a Windows Phone 8 application is invoking a `System.OutOfMemoryException`. I wanted to use `Process.GetCurrentProcess();` to examine available memory but have been unable to find it as it doesn't appear to exist in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Is my only option to start trying to call the Windows API directly (assuming that's even possible)? My real reason for wanting to get the current process was in determining the total available memory to my application.

Any help kindly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is the code

```
public async static Task<T> InvokeServiceAsync<T>(string BaseAddress, string Path, params object[] ParamArray)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}", Path, MvcUtilities.BuildWebApiRequest(ParamArray)));            
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    T result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>(); //Out of memory exception
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Phone apps can't start processes nor enumerate them.  The winapi loophole is closed as well, enforced by the SDK headers, certification and the sandbox.  Even if it were available then it would be very unlikely that code could run in an OOM condition.

It is never another process that causes it, Phone runs a virtual memory demand-paged operating system.  Recovering from OOM is extremely difficult, there's very little point in trying.  You need to make do with less allocations.

Comment: Just to be clear its not about me recovering from the OutOfMemoryException, its just about me trying to understand how much memory is available to me as a developer within my app. I had only used 30-40mb of memory.

Comment: Technically it is possible for the exception to be raised by exhausting operating resources other than virtual memory.  Your question as posted gives no hints to what that might be, at least a stack trace is required.  Looking at other processes is never going to give you a hint at all.

Comment: I do understand that there may be other reasons for the exception but that's not really the issue, at the end of the day surely there is some way for me to determine currently available memory? Either way I'll update with exact code to provide a better context. PS: Appreciate your input!

Comment: Available memory is a fixed number, every 32-bit process gets 2 gigabytes.  If you know for a fact that you've consumed 40 megabytes then you've still got 1960 megabytes left.  Do make sure you distinguish virtual memory from RAM, two very different kinds of memory.  A process that uses 40 megabytes of RAM typically uses lots more virtual memory.  And no, there's no simple way to find out how much VM is left.

Comment: @HansPassant: I thought this is about Windows Phone 8, where there is also a fixed amount of RAM available for an application namely 150MB.